# how can i to chosen web page when clicking back

Tags: php, codeigniter, button, redirect, back

I have a php page(hard coded php), my objective is when the user clicked on the back button of the browser he will automatically redirected to other page (this page is written in code igniter).
I downloaded  [back button detect library](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/)
and tried already this methods in js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function(){
    //window.location.href =  "http://google.com";
    //window.history.back(-2);
    //window.navigate('http://google.com');
    //self.location='http://google.com';
    alert("back");
     window.history.back();
}
```

i tried also using $_SESSION (setting the value on hard coded php, and check the value on the codeigniter page if the value is the same i tried redirect them to the other page) but it does not working as well.

Thank you

Comment: So, if a user visiting your site clicks the back button, he gets redirected to another URL? 
I would STRONGLY recommend against this. It is never a good idea to overwrite default browser behavior.

Comment: be careful with this behaviour, users dont expect to be redirected to another page when they click back, what is the reason for this?

Comment: I will be more precise, when the user click on the back button he see the codeigniter page(it has many views) but the main view displaying the following message:
Confirm Form Resubmission message
and i don`t see the view itself and because of that i thought to redirect the user directly when he clicks on the back button

Comment: If you're looking to avoid the `Confirm form resubmission` message, maybe you should use `GET` instead of `POST` on your form submission? I strongly advise you not to mess with the browser's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it! Your users will get very confused and probably very angry if the browser itself does not perform how they expect. It would be much better to have a button within your site that redirects the user to where you want them to go, but make sure that it is very clear what the button does. 
I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but if you are seeing the "Confirm Form Resubmission" message this is a standard browser message when the page that is being loaded is the result of a form submission.

Comment: In CI there is two pages, when the user chooses how much to pay and then he clicks on the pay button, the script will redirect him to another page where he need to wait 10 seconds and after that he will be redirected (there is a form that submitted automatically) to the hard coded php page, the problem accrues when the user is clicking back from that page